# SqlQuery SUM of values in Postgres DB (Raw SQL query)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm trying to SUM a set of values using SqlQuery in .NET 7.

```
var totalTime = await this.Context
                          .Database
                          .SqlQuery<int>($"SELECT \"SUM\"(extract(day from(NOW()-\"stripe_created_date\"))::integer) FROM stripe.\"subscription\" WHERE \"stripe_created_date\" >= {gte} AND \"status\" <> 'incomplete_expired' AND \"status\" <> 'incomplete' AND \"status\" <> 'canceled'")
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I get:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: function SUM(integer) does not exist

The query works fine outside C# land.

Comment: Why "SUM" with quotes? Remove quotes: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TB2FhM23).

Comment: Without the quotes, it seems to assume it is a column, I get this error:

42703: column t.Value does not exist

POSITION: 8

Comment: There is no `t.Value` in your query?

Comment: @Charlieface, can you elaborate?

Comment: You say that you get an error `column t.Value does not exist` but you have no such reference in your SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need the quotes around SUM but the underlying issue was that SqlQuery doesn't support scalar values.

Consequently, EF does not know the column name that is being returned. To get around this, you add "AS Value" which is the "column name" EF looks for in the output.

I amended my code to the following:

```
var totalTime = await this.Pnk1Context
                                      .Database
                                      .SqlQuery<int>($"SELECT SUM(extract(day from(NOW()-stripe_created_date))::integer) AS \"Value\" FROM stripe.subscription WHERE stripe_created_date >= {gte} AND status <> 'incomplete_expired' AND status <> 'incomplete' AND status <> 'canceled'")
                                      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30447 for more a better explanation.